# How to identify abstract members via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Given the follwing class - I would like to know which of the both members is abstract:

```
abstract class Test
{
  public abstract bool Abstract { get; set; }
  public bool NonAbstract { get; set; }
}

var type = typeof( Test );
var abs = type.GetProperty( "Abstract" );
var nonAbs = type.GetProperty( "NonAbstract" );

// now, something like:
if( abs.IsAbstract ) ...
```

Unfortunately there is nothing like the `IsAbstract`-property.
I need to select all non-abstract fields/properties/methods of a class - but there are no `BindingFlags` to narrow the selection, too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A property is actually some 'syntactic sugar', and is implemented by 2 methods: a getter method and a setter method.

So, I think that you should be able to determine if a property is abstract by checking if the getter and/or setter are abstract, like this:

```
PropertyInfo pi = ...

if( pi.GetSetMethod().IsAbstract )
{
}
```

And, AFAIK, a field cannot be abstract. ;)

Comment: Yeah, the abstract field is stupid - thanks for the answer. Your solution is working for private properties, too, which is important for me.

Answer (score 1):

First off: fields can't be abstract, since all there is to them is the field itself.

Next we note that properties are (in a loose sense!) actually get_/set_ methods under the hood.

Next we check what *does* have an `IsAbstract` property, and see that `MethodBase` (and so `MethodInfo`) does.

Finally we remember/know/find out that a `PropertyInfo` has `GetGetMethod()` and `GetSetMethod()` methods that return `MethodInfo`s, and we're done, except for filling in the messy details about inheritance and so forth.

Comment: Until now, I did not try to create abstract fields ... :) I was just writing faster than thinking. Thanks for your suggestion.